# Auto answering password for OPENSSL using HEREDOC

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

I have the following command but it doesn't work for me...

```
cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ && openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
password
PASS
```

**UPDATE:**

The output is:

```
109 semi-random bytes loaded
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
...............................++++++
...........++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for smtpd.key:
```

It should auto answer the question and put password automaticaly.

I always use `HEREDOC` for automating my Q&A on bash and work fine...

What is the problem here?

Comment: Defeating the purpose of security!

Comment: In what way does it not work? Please describe the problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29186

Comment: @John Zwinck I'll test it... I think this is a good help

Comment: @John Zwinck you can modify that answer here to be accepted...

Comment: I tried posting a short answer but the site turned it into a comment.  How about if you post your own solution that works for you as an answer, and folks can vote for it.  :)

Comment: No, honestly I am trying without getting answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Graeme said [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118059/auto-answering-used-by-heredoc-doesnt-work-now)

I can do with heredoc like so:

I have to add `-passout stdin` for openssl to read from stdin.

```
cd /etc/postfix/ssl/ && openssl genrsa  -passout stdin -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 <<PASS
password
PASSW
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL (and OpenSSH) takes measures to read the password directly from the terminal, rather than from stdin, as a security measure.

However there are a load of ways to supply passwords to OpenSSL. Check `man openssl` for the section `PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS`.

So you could do:

```
  openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 -passout "pass:mypassword"
```

... but per the manpage: "Since the password is visible to utilities (like 'ps' under Unix) this form should only be used where security is not important"

Or you could do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PASS" | {
    openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 -passout fd:3
} 3<&0
```

... which is supposedly more secure than other options because the password won't show up in ps.

Comment: File descriptors. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html -- useful stuff.

Comment: I run the first and second solution...but It doesn't answer automaticaly

Comment: We should change something. It is working now: `openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:test -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024`

Comment: For second solution: Should I define a variable like: `PASS="test"` then ==> `printf '%s\n' "$PASS" | {
    openssl genrsa -des3 -passout fd:3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024 
} 3<&0`     ?????

Comment: Yes. $PASS needs to contain the password.